# =SUM() formula not functioning properly in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that I am working on that models a *Hardy-Weinberg population* through multiple generations.

I have a set of two numbers that represent *allele frequencies*. There are two columns of 'gamete' cells which display "A" if a randomly generated number is less than the first allele freq. cell, and a "B" if not.

The column next to them concatenates them.

There are then three columns (AA, AB, and BB) that output "1" if the concatenated cell matches the column's genotype (for the AB column I have to check for both "AB" and "BA") and "0" if not.

Below these columns I have cells that add all of the above cells together for a total of individuals with that genotype. However, these cells aren't working. Below is the formula that I have in one of the cells:

```
=SUM(H3:H32)
```

This has worked for me in the past, but not now. The cell simply outputs '0' at all times, even when '1' cells are present in its column.

I have checked, and Automatic Recalculation is on, the genotype cells are all numeric cells, and there aren't any circular references.

EDIT: Here is the formula for the 'AA' column:

```
=IF(G3="AA","1","0")
```

...the formula for the 'AB' column:

```
=IF(OR(G3="AB",G3="BA"),"1","0")
```

...and the formula for the 'BB' column:

```
=IF(G3="BB","1","0")
```

Comment: What error are you experiencing? Error values or incorrect sums? Does it also happen if you just copy the values to a new sheet and sum them there?

Comment: It simply outputs '0', even though there are '1' cells in its column. I have not tested that, but I can check.

Comment: Have you thought about using a COUNTIF() instead and skipping the step of creating the 1's and 0's?

Comment: This is part of an assignment, and the teacher wants us to create the spreadsheet in this manner. This allows us to test for certain variables (like genetic drift, natural selection, etc.). Also, I'm not that well versed in Excel functions, so I had no prior knowledge of this function.

Comment: Are the cells assigned as numbers?

Comment: Yes. They were assigned as General before, but I then assigned them as Numbers. The SUM() function still didn't add them.

Comment: What are your formulas that put the 1 or the 0?

Comment: Here, I'll add them into the Q.

Comment: Remove the quotes around the 1's and 0's.  You are assigning them as text so the SUM() does not pick them up.

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you! Could you create an answer that includes that so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple. Your "IF" condition is what is breaking things for you. Even if your cell is in numerical format, your "IF" condition is imputing a string in the cell and not an integer. Strings cannot be added in a "SUM" function. You should remove the quotes in your condition and it will then input an integer instead of a string. I tested this and it works. Try the following:

```
=IF(G3="AA",1,0)
```

You should do this for all your "IF" functions that should generate an integer that will be added further on in a SUM function.

Edit: Just realized that this answer was given in the above comments, sorry for duplicating it.

Comment: No, this is good. It means that other people having this problem can find the answer more easily.

Comment: No one should ever get upset by there comment being put as an answer.

Comment: Great! glad to hear that. I was just trying to help :)